# Angular number formatting – separating each thousand with empty space

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to format each number – some are being defined directly in the HTML template, some with @ViewChild textContent in TS – to look like this 1 213.00.

After each thousand the empty space should appear.

How can I manage that so it's possible to be implemented in both HTML and TS?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'removeComma'
})
export class RemoveCommaPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string | null): string {
    if (value !== undefined && value !== null) {
      return value.replace(/,/g, " ");
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your template:

```
{{ decimalValue | number | removeComma }}
```

Where number is Angular's built-in decimal pipe.

In your class:

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { RemoveCommaPipe } from 'your-custom-pipe-path';

constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe, private removeCommaPipe: RemoveCommaPipe) {
}
...
decimalValue = 1234567;
this.removeCommaPipe.transform(this.decimalPipe.transform(this.decimalValue))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know, how to use toFixed(2) with that? For now, it's not working properly but I need to show all numbers with 2 decimal points precision.

Comment: Yes. Like this: `{{ decimalValue | number:'1.2-2' | removeComma }}`

Comment: Yes, in HTML your solution is useful, I am trying to implement transform() and toFixed() in TS file instead.

Comment: Try `this.removeCommaPipe.transform(this.decimalPipe.transform(this.decimalValue, '1.2-2'))`